# Mod_Rewrite Query with Root Domain

Tags: php, string, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a query on some information if someone types, for example:

```
http://domain.com/abracadabra
```

If someone enters in this address, I want it to go to:

```
search.php?query=abracadabra
```

I've done rewrites with queries before, but not from the root.
Any help would be great!

Would it be possible to check if the string being searched is numerical and send it to a different PHP page? Maybe link to a directory with a new .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it from the root is no different than doing it anywhere else. The below will turn every request for a resource (that doesn't exist in the file system) to `search.php`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: you are going to want to put this **underneath** any existing rules you may have as this rule will capture any url (that's not a file or folder)

Comment: Just curious - what do the L and QSA flags do? I thought they appended to the original? Either way.. this worked! Thanks :D

Also, is there a way to include PHP logic into .htaccess? For example, if the search string is numeric, it uses a different PHP file than search.php.

Comment: `QSA`appends query string to the request. `L` means it's the last rule, so it'll ignore subsequent rules if it matches. [Read more about RewriteRule flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). You can't include PHP in .htaccess, but you can match only numbers using regular expressions. `^(.*)$` is the regex currently being matched. Replace it with `^([\d]+)$` to only match numbers.